# WampServer - Restart Apache from script.bat

Tags: apache, wampserver

How to restart apache from 
[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) using a .bat file?

Answer (score 4):

Both Apache and MySQL run as a service ( by default ) so all you need to do is stop/start the service as you would from the command line.

The Apache service is called `wampapache` and the MySQL service is called `wampmysql`

So in a batch file your would do :-

```
net stop wampmysql
net stop wampapache

net start wampmysql
net start wampapache
```

Of course you would have to run the batch file from a userid that has the privilages to stop and start services.

**UPDATE for x64:**

The Apache and MySQL services for 64-bit systems are called `wampapache64` and `wampapache64`, so the command should be

```
net stop wampapache64
net stop wampmysqld64
```

Answer (score 4):

Run as administrator

```
net stop wampapache64 && net start wampapache64
```